# Read list of files and copy deleted files back

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I did a mercurial merge which deleted a few files which i need in the new branch so i generated a list of the deleted files and am now trying to build a shell script to copy the deleted files back but so far it is not working.The script is question is

```
cat deltedfiles | xargs -I {} bash -c 'cut -d" " -f1 "{}"|grep -Fq "R" && echo {}'
```

Can somebody tell me how do i correct this?
I just get an error from cut saying that the file does not exist and the whole line which i understand to be is cut is treating it as a file.

EDIT:
I created the list of files and saved it to a text file named deletdfiles using hg status.
In the script i'll replace echo at the end with cp command this was just to test if i can atleast get it to echo.

The deltedfiles looks likes this

```
cat deltedfiles
I did a mercurial merge which deleted a few files which i need in the new branch so i generated a list of the deleted files and am now trying to build a shell script to copy the deleted files back but so far it is not working.The script is question is

cat deltedfiles | xargs -I {} bash -c 'cut -d" " -f1 "{}"|grep -Fq "R" && echo {}'
```

Can somebody tell me how do i correct this?
I just get an error from cut saying that the file does not exist and the whole line which i understand to be is cut is treating it as a file.

EDIT:
I created the list of files and saved it to a text file named deletdfiles using hg status.
In the script i'll replace echo at the end with cp command this was just to test if i can atleast get it to echo.

The deltedfiles looks likes this

```
cat deltedfiles
R python/cmsintegration/events/migrations/0002_improved_navigation.py
R python/cmsintegration/events/migrations/0003_sitemap_fields.py
R python/cmsintegration/events/migrations/0004_cache_differentiation.py
R python/cmsintegration/events/migrations/0005_cms_displayables_seo.py
R python/cmsintegration/events/migrations/0006_nav_has_changed.py
R python/cmsintegration/events/migrations/0007_compute_nav_order.py
R python/cmsintegration/events/migrations/0008_adding_mob_reg_link.py
```

After running the above command this is the output

```
cut: R python/cmsintegration/events/migrations/0002_improved_navigation.py: No such file or directory
cut: R python/cmsintegration/events/migrations/0003_sitemap_fields.py: No such file or directory
cut: R python/cmsintegration/events/migrations/0004_cache_differentiation.py: No such file or directory
cut: R python/cmsintegration/events/migrations/0005_cms_displayables_seo.py: No such file or directory
cut: R python/cmsintegration/events/migrations/0006_nav_has_changed.py: No such file or directory
cut: R python/cmsintegration/events/migrations/0007_compute_nav_order.py: No such file or directory
cut: R python/cmsintegration/events/migrations/0008_adding_mob_reg_link.py: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Question and the script(command line); they do not correlate to me. Little more background and explanation will be helpful. And why you arent ousing `cut -d` instead of using with `bash -c `

Comment: Removing the bash -c isn't much helpful, actually i was trying out different things to get it to work

Comment: please provide deltedfiles content and what you are trying to do! with last grep

Comment: Is this more helpful?

Comment: If user000001 solves your problem then please accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, something like this could work:

```
$ while read -r _ file; do echo "$file" "otherdir/$file"; done < deltedfiles
python/cmsintegration/events/migrations/0002_improved_navigation.py newfolder/python/cmsintegration/events/migrations/0002_improved_navigation.py
python/cmsintegration/events/migrations/0003_sitemap_fields.py newfolder/python/cmsintegration/events/migrations/0003_sitemap_fields.py
python/cmsintegration/events/migrations/0004_cache_differentiation.py newfolder/python/cmsintegration/events/migrations/0004_cache_differentiation.py
python/cmsintegration/events/migrations/0005_cms_displayables_seo.py newfolder/python/cmsintegration/events/migrations/0005_cms_displayables_seo.py
python/cmsintegration/events/migrations/0006_nav_has_changed.py newfolder/python/cmsintegration/events/migrations/0006_nav_has_changed.py
python/cmsintegration/events/migrations/0007_compute_nav_order.py newfolder/python/cmsintegration/events/migrations/0007_compute_nav_order.py
python/cmsintegration/events/migrations/0008_adding_mob_reg_link.py newfolder/python/cmsintegration/events/migrations/0008_adding_mob_reg_link.py
```

Replace `echo` with `cp` if it produces the correct output.

If you only want to copy the files that are in a line that starts with the word `R` you
can do it like this:

```
while read -r letter file _ ; do [[ $letter = "R" ]] && echo "$file" "otherdir/$file"; done < deltedfiles
```

Or in a more readable format:

```
while read -r letter file _ 
do 
    [[ $letter = "R" ]] && echo "$file" "otherdir/$file"
done < deltedfiles
```

Comment: This works but it includes all the files, i just want the files with the R in the first column as in the output there are other rows which start with other letters

Comment: @Shaumux Gotcha. Try the new version.