# How to do reach specific section of text file and then search

Tags: regex, linux, awk

I have a text file like

```
Apples
Big 7
Small 6

Apples
Good 5
Bad 3

Oranges
Big 4
Small 2
Good 1
Bad 5
```

How do I get to specific section of this file and then do a grep? For example, If I need to find how many Good Oranges are there, how do I do it from command line with this file as input, using say awk?

Comment: I'm guessing the blank lines between each line were inserted manually when you wrote the question. Should they be removed?

Comment: As you accepted my answer, I assume that there are blank lines between each section. Please edit the question if my assumption is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the range operator like this:

```
awk '/Apples/,/^$/ { if (/Good/) print $2}' file
```

would print how many good apples there are:

```
5
```

The range operator `,` will evaluate to true when the first condition is satisfied and remain true until the second condition. The second pattern `/^$/` matches a blank line. This means that only the relevant sections will be tested for the property Good, Bad, etc.

---

I'm assuming that your original input file wasn't double-spaced? If it was, the method above can be patched to skip every other line:

```
awk '!NR%2{next} /Oranges/,/^$/ { if (/Good/) print $2}' file
```

When the record number `NR` is even, NR%2 is `0` and `!0` is true so every other line will be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

When you have name/value pairs, it's usually best to first build an array indexed by the name and containing the value, then you can just print whatever you're interested in using the appropriate name(s) to index the array:

```
$ awk 'NF==1{key=$1} {val[key,$1]=$2} END{print val["Oranges","Good"]}' file
1

$ awk 'NF==1{key=$1} {val[key,$1]=$2} END{print val["Apples","Bad"]}' file
3
```

or if you're looking for the starting point to implement a more complete/complex set of requirements here's one way:

```
$ awk '
NF {
    if (NF==1) {
        key=$1
        keys[key]
    }
    else {
        val[key,$1]=$2
        names[$1]
    }
}
END {
    for (key in keys)
        for (name in names)
            print key, name, val[key,name]
}
' file
Apples Big 7
Apples Bad 3
Apples Good 5
Apples Small 6
Oranges Big 4
Oranges Bad 5
Oranges Good 1
Oranges Small 2
```

To test @JohnB's theory that a shell script would be faster than an awk script if there were thousands of files, I copied the OPs input file 5,000 times into a tmp directory then ran these 2 equivalent scripts on them (the bash one based on Johns answer in this thread and then an awk one that does the same as the bash one):

```
$ cat tst.sh
for file in "$@"; do
    while read -r field1 field2 ; do
        [ -z "$field2" ] && name="$field1"
        case $name in
            Oranges) [ "$field1" = "Good" ] && echo "$field2";;
        esac
    done < "$file"
done
```

.

```
$ cat tst.awk
NF==1 { fruit=$1 }
fruit=="Oranges" && $1=="Good" { print $2 }
```

and here's the results of running both on those 5,000 files:

```
$ time ./tst.sh tmp/* > bash.out
real    0m6.490s
user    0m2.792s
sys     0m3.650s
```

.

```
$ time awk -f tst.awk tmp/* > awk.out
real    0m2.262s
user    0m0.311s
sys     0m1.934s
```

The 2 output files were identical.

Comment: +1 The only dowside with this approach is the file might be too big to fit in memory.

Comment: Yeah, it's unlikely but if that does happen there's the easy tweak to print+delete whenever the key changes so you only hold the info for 1 key in memory at a time.

Comment: You just didn't want to use the range operator, did you ;)

Comment: Just wasn't the right approach for this one IMHO. name/value pairs in the input really draw you to the above array type of solution.

Comment: What if fruit does have two names, like `Goji berry` `Blood Orange` etc.

Comment: Then the OP needs to shows us a sample of that and tell us how to differentiate the keys from the name/value pairs (e.g. the name/value pair lines end in digits).

Comment: If so, you could use `$NF!~/^[0-9]+$/`

Comment: Or just `!/[[:digit:]]/` with or without a trailing `$` would probably be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Bash to read from the file line by line in a loop.

```
while read -a fruit; do
    [ ${#fruit[@]} -eq 1 ] && name=${fruit[0]}
    case $name in
        Oranges) [ "${fruit[0]}" = "Good" ] && echo ${fruit[1]};;
    esac
done < file
```

You could also make this a function and pass it arguments to get trait information about any fruit.

```
read_fruit (){
    while read -a fruit; do
        [ ${#fruit[@]} -eq 1 ] && name=${fruit[0]}
        case $name in
            $1) [ "${fruit[0]}" = "$2" ] && echo ${fruit[1]};;
        esac
    done < file
}
```

Use:

```
read_fruit Apples Small
```

result:

```
6
```

Comment: bash is a UNIX shell. A UNIX shell is an environment from which to call UNIX tools with a language to sequence those calls. The UNIX tool to parse text files is awk. Any time you find yourself writing a shell loop to parse text files you have the wrong approach.

Comment: To say Awk is the only tool anyone should use to parse a text file is closed minded.  There are pros and cons to both for different situations.  Instead of just saying Awk is better than Bash, I'd be more open to listening about why particularly for this situation, you disagree.  Especially in situations where the file is relatively small in size, usage of other UNIX tools other than Awk is mostly personal preference.  I think it's clear where your preference is ;)

Comment: awk is the general-purpose text-parsing tool that comes with every UNIX installation. I'm not suggesting you shouldn't use sed, grep, tr, etc. for simple things, but that you should not use a shell loop. Awk has builtin support for reading single or multi-line records, splitting records into fields, and requires no manual coding to safeguard against characters in the input file (e.g. partially depending on what files exist in the directory from which you execute that command, it could convert `\ `s, `?`s, `*`s, etc. to something else as part of the the `read` and/or `echo` statements).

Comment: Basically, a "shell" loop to parse a text file is lengthier, less robust, requires more hand coding, usually slower to execute and IMHO is just generally more complicated than an equivalent awk script so there's just no value to doing that.

Comment: @EdMorton I agree that in most cases (like this one) files shouldn't be parsed by shell loops. On the other hand, there are legitimate cases for it, e.g. when calling a command on the loop, like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23867579/828193. Calling `cp` from `awk` wouldn't be optimal, right?

Comment: You both make some good points, but I think it's ok to prefer avoiding a call to a separate interpreter such as Awk in situations where the shell can do the job just as well on it's own.

Comment: @user000001 Yes, it is appropriate to have a shell loop to call shell commands to manipulate files and/or processes based on the contents of a text file. That's largely what the shell looping constructs are for. I'm only referring to writing shell loops to just parse text file contents. John - unfortunately shell can't do the job just as well on it's own as it doesn't have the builtin support for that job but instead has builtin support to do something different by default (e.g. globbing, word splitting, etc.) which you then need to write code to disable. It's just a tool for a different job.

Comment: Ed - The shell can't do the job just as well as Awk on its own in many situations but in fact can do it better in others.  Take this post as an example.  Say someone has thousands of small files they need to run this on.  It would take much longer to call Awk each time than it would to use only the shell.

Comment: @JohnB I decided to test it and with 5,000 files identical to the OPs posted sample input, an awk script ran twice as fast as an equivalent bash script. See my updated answer. Note also that the bash script was 4 times the size of the awk script and more complicated.

Comment: @EdMorton Awk is indeed faster if used the way you tested.  When I tested using `time` I used Bash to run Awk for each file as Awk was being passed varying fruits and traits, not just `Oranges` and `Good` every time.  After doing a google, I realized variables can be set for an Awk script from the shell, in which case using an Awk script would also be faster.  However, I still think since performance is negligible in many cases, there is no reason to say Awk should always be used.  That said, this discussion urges me to become more comfortable using Awk as it's a better tool for many tasks.

Comment: Sounds good. To be clear, I'm not saying you should use awk for every task, just that you should always use it instead of writing a loop in shell simply to parse a text file. I agree that performance isn't a significant consideration, I would never have brought that up, I was just addressing the point in your previous comment. Simplicity, brevity, clarity and robusteness are the reasons to prefer awk. Glad to hear you'll be looking at awk a bit harder in future.